# Any nonempty subset of a directed-complete partial order $(X,\leq)$ has a supremum if $X$ is a join-semilattice?

Tags: solution-verification, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a directed-complete partial order
([dcpo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_partial_order)),
and let $W$ be a nonempty subset of $X$.

Suppose that $(X,\leq)$ is also a join-semilattice.
Then the join $\vee A$ of any nonempty, finite subset $A$ of $W$ exists.
Let
\begin{equation*}
U = \{\vee A:A\text{ is a nonempty, finite subset of }W\}.
\end{equation*}
Then $U$ is an upward directed subset of $X$,
and as $X$ is a dcpo it follows that $U$ has a supremum $\vee U$.

Since $W$ is a subset of $U$, any upper bound of $U$ is an upper bound of $W$.

Conversely,
if $x$ is an upper bound of $W$
then it is an upper bound of any nonempty, finite subset $A$ of $W$,
and so it is an upper bound of $U$.

It follows that $W$ has a supremum, and it equals $\vee U$.

Is my reasoning correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  (But the usual notation for the join of a set $A$ is $\bigvee A$, not $\lor A$; the TeX command is \bigvee.)

Comment: When you ask whether your solution is correct, you should probably use the `solution-verification` tag.

Comment: @MarkSaving I will add it. Thanks, I didn't know that tag existed.